# Sql как сделать форму для номер телефона?

Tags: sql

Я новичок в создании таблиц в sql. Как я могу сделать так, чтобы поле для ввода номера телефона выглядело так: +7[Поле для ввода 10 цифр]?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на СО.  Ваш вопрос странный.  *SQL* — язык запросов.  Никаких форм и полей ввода вы на нём не сделаете при всём желании.  Добавьте в вопрос и в метки вашу среду разработки или фреймворк.

Comment: @Ainar-G, я думаю, здесь имеется в виду создать поле в таблице, в котором могут содержаться только значения по заданному шаблону. Но и в этом случае все равно не хватает указания используемой СУБД.

Comment: Ок, я буду более подробен. Делаю приложение на Windows Forms в Visual Studio с использованием Sql. Мне нужно, чтобы при вводе в форму для номера телефона, человек мог ввести только номер и ничего другого. У меня есть идея, что можно ограничить ввод в поле только 10 знаками(+7 и 10 знаков после), но я думал, что люди тут могут подсказать что-то получше.

Comment: Это делается с помощью регулярных выражений.\

Comment: В Postgresql есть [check constraint](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-check-constraint/)

Comment: вот так подробнее и надо было с самого начала, явно же проще решать задачу, когда есть исчерпывающее количество информации? удачи с вопросом